# htaccess url with regex to forbidden

Tags: .htaccess

I need to block all request made with a specific url like

```
http://www.domain.est/-p-.html?slave_id=15265&osCsid=6j0ltvo8d9i8h30koahqusvua7
```

I tried with

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(\/-p-\.html)+(\?slave_id\=\d{1,6})?(\&osCsid\=\w{1,26})? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

but doesn't work. 
Where I'm wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a version that is easier to handle and should be more robust too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/-p-\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} slave_id=[0-9]{1,6}
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} osCsid=[0-9a-z]{1,26}
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

*Note: the query args matching patterns are not absolutely precise, but should be robust enough for almost all situations...*

---

For this to work the http servers rewrite module has to be enabled, obviously. The rules will work in the http servers host configuration or in dynamic configurtation files (`.htaccess`). In case you decide to use such a dynamic configuration file you also have to take care to enable the interpretation of such files with the `AllowOverride` directive in the host configuration and the file has to be located in your http hosts configured `DocumentRoot` folder.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank's !! Work's very well.